# Separation of $X$ - open and closed subsets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, connectedness

I'm trying to decipher some notes from a lecture I missed. What I have is:

> If $U$, $V$ is a separation of $X$, then $U = X \setminus V$, $V = X \setminus U$. So $U$ and $V$ are open and closed subsets of $X$ not $X$, $\varnothing$.

What does the "not $X$, $\varnothing$" part mean? Everything else makes sense, but this part seems to be an incomplete thought that the lecturer probably filled in verbally.

Comment: I think it just means that both $U$ and $V$ are neither $X$ nor empty.

Comment: @ArnaudD. But by definition $U$ and $V$ are already non-empty and hence neither one can be $X$.

Comment: What definition?

Comment: @user254665 Of what a separation is, as suggested by the connectedness tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means $U$ and $V$ are not equal to $X$ or $\emptyset$.  The point is that open and closed sets always exist in any space (namely, $X$ and $\emptyset$), but to get a separation you need sets which are open and closed and are different from the trivial examples $X$ and $\emptyset$.

Comment: This seems to be it. I think he was trying to make a point that indeed that $U$ and $V$ cannot be $X$ or $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a guess, but I suppose that this sentence was related with the notion of [connected set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) (as suggested by one of your tags). Now if $X$ is not connected, then $X$ is a disjoint union of two nonempty open sets $U$ and $V$. Then $U \cup V = X$, $U$ and $V$ are different from $\emptyset$ and $X$,
$X \setminus U = V$, $X \setminus V= U$, and $U$ and $V$ are clopen. Would it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your definition is very much correct! It wasn't this which confused me, but I simply couldn't figure out why the non trivial part was there when it's obvious. It seems that it was there to hammer that pont home, which the other answer helped me realise. Have an upvote however!